# Continuous bijection between an annulus + a point and the open unit disk

Tags: general-topology, analysis, continuity

The open annulus with a point I define as $\{ (r,\theta)\colon 1<r<2,0\leq \theta < 2\pi \}\bigcup \{\left(1,0\right)\}$.  Call that $A$.  Let $B=\{(r,\theta)\colon 0\leq r<1, 0\leq \theta < 2\pi\}$; the open unit disk.

I want to find a continuous bijection $f:A \to B$.  My first idea was $f(r-1,\theta)$.  My intuition here is I am trying to "collapse" the annulus into the origin of the unit disk.The function maps everything on the inner rim of the annulus near the origin, and the point $\left(1,0\right)$ to the origin.  Injectivity I have.  I'm stuck on surjectivity.

To check if this is a bijection:

One-to-one?
This is one-to-one.  Fix $\theta$.  Let $r_1,r_2\in A$ such that $r_1 \neq r_2$.  Then $f((r_1,\theta))\neq f((r_2,\theta)) \Rightarrow (r_1-1,\theta)\neq(r_2-1,\theta)$.

Onto?
Let $r\in B$.  Then we want to make sure that the preimage of $f^{-1}(r)\neq \emptyset$.  Well for any $r \in B$, the preimage will be $r+1$. So for the origin, it will be mapped to $(1,0)$.

I'm actually stuck on proving this is onto.  There might be a more efficient way to define the two objects so as to make surjective-ness appear more apparent.

Comment: I'm not a topologist, but the annulus and the disk are not topologically equivalent -- the disk is simply connected, the annulus is not.  So I am doubtful you can find a continuous bijection.  The (r-1/2, theta) does not look like it maps into 0 at all.

Comment: That's why there is a point added, namely (1/2,0).

Comment: I've edited the question.  Hopefully its clearer.

Comment: @BettyMock we cannot find a homeomorphism, but does that mean we can't find a continuous bijection as well? Eugene: I believe your map works (although it's not open, naturally; the problem arises around $(1,0)$)

Comment: @Jonathan, thank you for this comment bringing my attention tothe difference between a continuous, bijective function and a homeomorphism.  I agree a homeomorphism would be much more restrictive.

Comment: @Eugene -- was the point (1,0) [or (1/2,0)]in the original problem?  If so I missed it.  This construction does add in an extra point one needs for the missing zero in B, so I would have to drop my original objection.  I do believe you have the "onto" part, in that you stated an inverse for everything in B.  How would you show continuity at (1,0)?  It seems it might be true in that (1,0) is a limit of points within the annulus, but it would be good to nail it down.

Comment: @Eugene --thinking it thru your inverse for z in B was not stated clearly.  If z = re^it then its precursor would be (r+1)z.  I presume that's what you meant.  Except of course for 0 but we know that came from (1,0).